# Intersection - Envelope

Tags: c#, collections, set, intersection, set-intersection

I have `Envelope[][] extents = new Envelope[][];` construction. Each envelope has `MinX`, `MaxX`, `MinY` and `MaxY` properties and represents one tile of a grid (bottom-left and top-right point). Now I have another `Envelope bounds;` which contains min and max values for `X-` and `Y-axis`. I want to get tiles from `extents` which intersects with `bounds`.

Is there any simple way to do this using `Envelope.Intersect`?

**[edit]**
For now I did it in this way (brute-force xD):

```
List<Envelope> intersectedTiles = new List<Envelope>();
for (int i = 0; i < extents.LongLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < extents.Length; j++)
    {
        if (extents[i][j].MinX >= bounds.MinX && extents[i][j].MaxX <= bounds.MaxX &&
            extents[i][j].MinY >= bounds.MinY && extents[i][j].MaxY <= bounds.MaxY)
        {
            intersectedTiles.Add(extents[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static bool Intersects(Envelope e1, Envelope e2)
{
    return e1.MinX >= e2.MinX && e1.MaxX <= e2.MaxX && e1.MinY >= e2.MinY && e1.MaxY <= e2.MaxY;
}

List<Envelope> intersectedTiles = extents.SelectMany(es => es)
    .Where(e => Intersects(e, bounds))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `e` in `Where` clausule is `null` and `Intersects` returns `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Nickon - Then you have a null element somewhere in one of the arrays in `extents`. You can ignore them by changing the condition to `Where(e => e != null && Intersects(bounds, e))`, although removing nulls would be better.

Comment: Yeah, u're right... There was a problem with my calculations, that's why `null` appeared:) Now everything works fine, but I had to change `Intersects(bounds, e)` to `Intersects(e, bounds)`. Thanks